# Edges in a graph with girth greater than 4

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, co.combinatorics

According to the following paper by [Füredi](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~z-furedi/PUBS/furedi_C4abs.ps), the maximum number of edges for a graph with $n$ vertices is upper bounded by $O(n^{\frac{3}{2}})$, where the leading co-efficient of the term $n^{\frac{3}{2}}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$. The paper also provides examples of graphs, for certain special values of $n$, where the number of edges exactly equal to the upper bound.

I wanted to know there exists graphs G(V,E) ($|V| = n $) for all values of $n$ such that

$$\Big|E - \small{\frac{1}{2}}n^{\frac{3}{2}}\Big| = o\big(n^\frac{3}{2}\big)$$

Comment: What you want follows from the result of Füredi that you mentioned and the known bounds on gaps between primes (e.g. those of Baker-Harman-Pintz).

Comment: @BorisBukh comment -> answer?

Comment: No. It is not a research-level question.